# TableLayout background from URI

Tags: android, background, tablelayout

How to use the setBackgroundDrawable method on tablelayout with an URI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```